# Flutter project no longer building for windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart

Not sure what's caused it but for some reason my windows application no longer builds.

The error output is the following:

```
[  +60 ms] C:\Users\George\source\repos\ReactionTracking\src\ReactionTrackerClient\windows\runner\Runner.rc(125): error RC2135: file not found: + [C:\Users\George\source\repos\ReactionTracking\src\ReactionTrackerClient\build\windows\runner\reactions.vcxproj]
[   +1 ms] C:\Users\George\source\repos\ReactionTracking\src\ReactionTrackerClient\windows\runner\Runner.rc(129): error RC2135: file not found: + [C:\Users\George\source\repos\ReactionTracking\src\ReactionTrackerClient\build\windows\runner\reactions.vcxproj]
```

When I ctrl + click the path directly in VS Code terminal it opens the file fine, so I know the path is valid and the file exists.

Did some research and the closest to my issue I could find was an issue with spaces and special characters in the path, which I have removed as above.

I have deleted the `pubspec.lock`, tried moving the project into a different folder, running the build command in a terminal running as admin. It was working fine until recently. Wondering if anyone has had any similar issues recently and what they did to fix it?

EDIT

Here is my `flutter doctor -v` output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675], locale en-AU)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at C:\Users\George\source\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (7 weeks ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at E:\AppData\Android
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 33.0.0-rc1
    • ANDROID_HOME = E:\AppData\Android
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = E:\AppData\Android
    • Java binary at: E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.6)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32421.90
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.20348.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 100.0.4896.127
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 101.0.1210.53

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone stumbles onto this with the same issue. Still don't know the cause but removing and re-adding windows as a platform sorted it out.

Answer (score 4):

Solved by:

- Removing **windows** folder.
- Recreate it using `flutter create .` *Repairs and adds the missing files*.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting *build/windows* folder and after re running the application the same folder got created and the error stopped appearing